# Searching multiple files to define variable

Tags: python

With Python, I need to search a file for a string and use it to define a variable. If there are no matches in that file, it searches another file. I only have 2 files for now, but handling more is a plus. Here is what I currently have:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b[01] [01] '+dest+r'\b')
dalt=None
with open(os.path.join('path','to','file','file.dat'), 'r') as datfile:
    for line in datfile:
        if regex.search(line):
            params=line.split()
            dalt=int(params[1])
            break
if dalt is None:
    with open(os.path.join('different','file','path','file.dat'), 'r') as fdatfile:
        for line in fdatfile:
            if regex.search(line):
                params=line.split()
                dalt=int(params[1])
                break
if dalt is None:
    print "Not found, giving up"
    dalt=0
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like a loop would work but I'm not sure how exactly. I'm sure there are also ways to make the code more "safe", suggestions in addition to answers are appreciated.

I'm coding for Python 2.73

---

As requested, here is an example of what I am searching for:

The string I will have to search with is "KBFI"  (`dest`), and I want to find this line:

```
1 21 1 0 KBFI Boeing Field King Co Intl
```

Previously I had `if dest in line`, but in some cases `dest` can appear in other lines. So I switched to a regex that also matches the two digits before `dest`, which can be 0 or 1. This seems to be working fine at least most of the time (haven't identified any bad cases yet). Although based on [the spec](http://data.x-plane.com/file_specs/XP%20APT1000%20Spec.pdf), supposedly the right line will start with a `1`, so maybe the right search is:

```
r'^1\s.*'+dest
```

But I haven't tested that. I suppose a fairly exact search would be:

```
r'^1\s+\d{,5}\s+[01]\s+[01]\s+'+dest+r'\b'
```

Since the fields are `1`, up to five digit number (*this is what I need to return*), 0 or 1, 0 or 1, then the string I'm searching for. (I haven't done much regex so I'm learning)

Comment: What is your search algorithm? What are you looking for?

Comment: what is blah blah  blah?

Comment: Different file paths

Comment: Are all the files that need to be searched in one directory? Is there any specific order in which the files need to be searched? Is there a naming convention to the filenames, which can be used to determine the order in which they are to be read?

Comment: They are named the same (probably), but in different directories. Order of searching them does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileinput` can take a list of files:

```
regex = re.compile(regexstring)
dir1 = "path_to_dir/file.dat"
dir2 =   "path_to_dir2/file.dat"
import fileinput
import os

for line in  fileinput.input([dir1,dir2]): # pass all files to check 
    if regex.search(line):
        params = line.split()
        dalt = int(params[1])
        break # found it so leave the loop
    print(dalt)
else: # if we get here no file had what we want
    print "Not found, giving"
```

If you want all the files from certain directories with similar names use glob and whatever pattern you want to match:

```
import  glob
dir1 = "path_to_dir/"
dir2 =   "path_to_dir2/"
path1_files = glob.glob(dir1+"file*.dat")
path2_files = glob.glob(dir2+"file*.dat")
```

You might not actually need a regex either, a simple `in line` may be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try `fileinput`. `glob` may be helpful too. I was using `in line` at first but it needed to be more specific (I've put the regex in the question now).

Comment: can you add an example of a line and what you want to check it for, fileinput will do exactly what you want all it needs is a list of files and it will do the rest.

Comment: I edited the question with more info about what I'm searching for.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I added a `fileinput.close()` so I can call the function again later.

Comment: @Nattgew, no worries.